# Printing while travelling, how can one do it?

Tags: tickets, planning

I will be travelling in Poland and, only there, will I be able to do the check in and print some of the ticket I need.

How can I do this? I usually try to find a webcafe or something similar, but I've been in difficult situations where this was not possible.

Is there anyway of finding these resources before travelling or in the Internet?
Any good tips?

Comment: Is your issue a printer or an internet connection?

Comment: Printer. I mention internet cafes, because they usually have printers.

Comment: If you're willing to spend money, this might just be your thing - http://www.brother-usa.com/Mobile/ModelDetail.aspx?ProductID=PJ663&PG=26

Comment: Which city are you going to visit?

Comment: How about the hotel/hostel you are staying in? I know hotels usually do not mind that, not sure about hostels..

Comment: @MeNoTalk I am only statying in one hostel and very soon. I will be camping and using other accomodations. I am not sure they have a printer. I would prefer to know where to find one.

Comment: @KnightWhoSayNi krakow, zakopane, gdansk warsaw.

Answer (score 2):

First, are you sure you need to print your tickets? I know some trains require physical printed tickets but many trains, buses and airlines will be OK checking the ticket on a smartphone (if you have one).

Assuming you've already considered that and you do need to print the tickets then you have a few options.

Internet cafes are actually surprisingly common, although sometimes they're geared for locals rather than tourists and so don't advertise. Wikivoyage has a 'Connect' section for some of the places you're going (i.e. [here](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Krak%C3%B3w/Old_Town#Connect), and [here](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Warsaw#Connect)), there's also [cybercafes.com](http://www.cybercafes.com/) which I've never used but is throwing up decent results. Also you can ask around, look at local listings in newspapers, etc.

Major transport hubs will generally have either print shops or internet cafes nearby for exactly this reason.

Hotels and hostels will generally be able to print something for you. Normally that's just for guests but you may be able to use the facilities for a small fee or if you agree to get a snack or a drink in the bar. Alternatively at a higher end hotel you might be able to just use the business center simply because nobody will actually check you're staying there. If you talk to the front desk even if they can't help you they'll undoubtedly be able to direct you to the nearest place.

Libraries often have computers and printers for public use as well.

Just ask around, I'm pretty positive you'll be able to find a way to get stuff printed.